# Type Mismatch: Cannot convert from Seat to String

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, mismatch

I'm trying to explore with simple Arrays and constructors. My goal here is to read a file of text containing 7 sets of data. (As seen from code below, string, string, bool, ect.) but I'm having problems.

My expected result is to...
Read the file from the text file, and store that data in an Array (don't need a ArrayList since we know how much data it contains, 7 sets of data a line, with 17 lines of data), then print the information. I've already tried creating the Array, with the Method and constructor, as well as reading the file and assigning the correct datatypes to the Array fields, but I'm getting the error.

**"Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Seat to String."**

When I've got my second part of my constructor below, it's supposed to relate back to the constructor method at the top, whilst looking into the Array so it knows where to store the data, right? but I'm unsure why, unless I've made an error. Previously, I've built a successful ArrayList, but I'm finding it difficult to read the data, and as explained above, I don't need an elastic Array because I know the amount of data.

I've also tried changing the return type of initial constructor method (at the top) as well as changing the name(s) of the method(s) to see if it was looking at the correct thing. Arrays are really cool and useful so I'd love to know where I've gone wrong. My code is below.

````
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class seatReserveSystem2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        class Seat {
            
            String seatNum;
            String seatClass;
            boolean isWindow;
            boolean isAisle;
            boolean isTable;
            double seatPrice;
            String eMail;
            // Constructor
            Seat(String seatNum, String seatClass, boolean isWindow, boolean isAisle, boolean isTable, double seatPrice, String eMail) {
                this.seatNum = seatNum;
                this.seatClass = seatClass;
                this.isWindow = isWindow;
                this.isAisle = isAisle;
                this.isTable = isTable;
                this.seatPrice = seatPrice;
                this.eMail = eMail;
                
        }

    }
        
        String[] reserveSeats = new String[7];
            
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("seats.txt"));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int index = 0;
        
        while(reader.hasNext()) {
            String dataSeats = reader.nextLine();
            String[] dataSplit = dataSeats.split(" ");
            String seatNum = dataSplit[0];
            String seatClass = dataSplit[1];
            boolean isWindow = Boolean.parseBoolean(dataSplit[2]);
            boolean isAisle = Boolean.parseBoolean(dataSplit[3]);
            boolean isTable = Boolean.parseBoolean(dataSplit[4]);
            double seatPrice = Double.parseDouble(dataSplit[5]);
            String eMail = dataSplit[6];
            
            reserveSeats[index] = new Seat(seatNum, seatClass, isWindow, isAisle, isTable, seatPrice, eMail);
            index++;
        }
        
        
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `reserveSeats` array is of type `String` instead of `Seat`.

Simple solution is to change

```
String[] reserveSeats = new String[7];
```

to

```
Seat[] reserveSeats = new Seat[7];
```

Comment: Thanks so much, something so simple and I didn't see it. I must have confused myself. Thanks a bunch! You've answered my question. :)